# iCarousal select second index while loading the view

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I have a `iCarousel` in one view. Everything working fine for me. But my problem is, I want to keep the second index object at the center of the view when that view gets loaded.Am displaying totally three images in the carousel. Now the second image is loading at the right corner.I want to keep it in center while loading. How can I do this.? please share your ideas.

Comment: Add a sample code of what you tried and didn't work so people can better help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `iCarousel.m` you can use this after set upping the entire carousel view You can call this method:

```
[self scrollToItemAtIndex:2 duration:0];
```